# How to make tkinter counter when click on botton

Tags: python, tkinter

i'm beginner for python i try to make counter when click on button but its not working as i expect

what i really need when i click on button its will add number like 1,2,3 but this result is 1111111

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Counter")
root.geometry("100x100")

def count():
    c = 0
    c += 1
    entry.insert(0,c)

button = Button(text="Count",command = count,)
label = Label(text="Time")
entry = Entry(root)
label.pack(side = TOP , pady = 5)
entry.pack(side = TOP , pady = 5)
button.pack(side=TOP , pady = 5)
mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This work, try it:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Counter")
root.geometry("100x100")
global c

def count():
    global c
    c += 1
    entry.delete(0, 'end')
    entry.insert(0,c)

c=0
button = Button(text="Count",command = count,)
label = Label(text="Time")
entry = Entry(root)
label.pack(side = TOP , pady = 5)
entry.pack(side = TOP , pady = 5)
button.pack(side=TOP , pady = 5)
mainloop()
```

Comment: While this may be the correct code to the question, generally giving an explanation to the code is good. Code only answers are very low quality, and not encouraged. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300846/12708583) for reasons why.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very simple. You have to remove this line of code from the `count()` function

```
c = 0
```

and put it somewhere else.
REASON: When you put `c = 0` inside the `count()` function, the value of c gets reset to 0. If you put it near the beginning of the program, it won't be reset and the value will only be incremented when the button is clicked

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of the value of `c`, the number of clicks - this can be done with a closure, created with a mutable default parameter in the example below.

You also need to delete the text displayed in the entry, prior to displaying the new value:

```
import tkinter as tk


def count(_c=[0]):   # <-- this creates a closure that keeps track of the number of clicks.
    _c[0] += 1
    entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry.insert(0, _c[0])


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Counter")
root.geometry("100x100")

button = tk.Button(text="Count", command=count)
label = tk.Label(text="Time")

entry = tk.Entry(root)

label.pack(side=tk.TOP , pady=5)
entry.pack(side=tk.TOP , pady=5)
button.pack(side=tk.TOP , pady=5)

mainloop()
```

Alternatively, you could keep track of the value of `c` if you create it in the `global namespace`, and declare it `global` in the function.

```
import tkinter as tk


def count():
    global c
    c += 1
    entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry.insert(0, c)


c = 0

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Counter")
root.geometry("100x100")

button = tk.Button(text="Count", command=count)
label = tk.Label(text="Time")

entry = tk.Entry(root)

label.pack(side=tk.TOP , pady=5)
entry.pack(side=tk.TOP , pady=5)
button.pack(side=tk.TOP , pady=5)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I added namespace `partial`. Look in keyword button's command by adding `+1`

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial


def increment_counter(var: int, amount: int) -> int:
   result=var.get()
   result += amount
   
   var.set(result)

 
root=tk.Tk()
variable = tk.IntVar()
tk.Button(root, width=10, text="Increase",
          command=partial(increment_counter, variable, +1),
          fg='red', bg="white").grid(column=0, row=0,
          padx=20, pady=(10,0))
tk.Label(root, width=5, height=2, textvariable=variable,
         bg="white", font="Verdana 16 bold").grid(column=0,
         row=1,padx=20, pady=10)
    

root.mainloop()
```